# How to test Conversation bot localhost

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am currently following [Teams Conversation Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot) sample.  I have followed it to the letter as far as i can see.

## What works.

When i talk to the bot though the web view

[image]

I can see it hitting the code on my localhost.

```
 protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            turnContext.Activity.RemoveRecipientMention();

            switch (turnContext.Activity.Text.Trim())
            {
                case "MentionMe":
                    await MentionActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;

                case "UpdateCardAction":
                    await UpdateCardActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;

                case "Delete":
                    await DeleteCardActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;

                case "MessageAllMembers":
                    await MessageAllMembersAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;

                default:
                    var value = new JObject { { "count", 0 } };

                    var card = new HeroCard
                    {
                        Title = "Welcome Card",
                        Text = "Click the buttons below to update this card",
                        Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                        {
                            new CardAction
                            {
                                Type= ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                                Title = "Update Card",
                                Text = "UpdateCardAction",
                                Value = value
                            },
                            new CardAction
                            {
                                Type = ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                                Title = "Message all members",
                                Text = "MessageAllMembers"
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment()));
                    break;
            }
        }
```

## what doesn't work

It appears to send the response back but nothing appears in the response window.  How do i test this if it doesn't show the response?

## Ngrok error

After a bit more digging I can see that ngrok is getting an error back of sorts its a web page I managed to pick the following error out of it.

> AggregateException: Failed to acquire token for client credentials. (AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '9e0d71-7665-4f24-8898-f82f9bebba56' was not found in the directory 'botframework.com'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
>   Trace ID: 4bf53bae-84dc-4b16-98e8-e99b322dc200
>   Correlation ID: 3c249469-d177-49dd-989f-80044a3b9faa
>   Timestamp: 2019-11-12 08:41:56Z) (AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'e0d71-7665-4f24-8898-f82f9bebba56' was not found in the directory 'botframework.com'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

I have checked the settings on the bot and the application itself.  They have the same secret and application client id.

[image]

botframework.com appears to contain a list of bots that were created on azure.

## What i have tried.

- Visual studio is running as administrator.
- Chcked[botframework.com](https://dev.botframework.com/bots) my bot is listed.
- Users have the write to create apps in AD, I am currently the only user anyway.

[image]

- dev tools logs shows its authenticating.
- Edge and chrome

[image]

## web chat errors

I can see in the bot that its logging errors with the web chat

[image]

The thing is the bot is responding.

## Emulator

Running the emulator does work.  The issue is when hosted.

## cross posted

Issue #[1974](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1974)

Comment: Are you running the local bot as an administrator or not?

Comment: Not. Would it matter if its calling the code?  Let me just restart it.

Comment: No change running visual studio as administrator.

Comment: It sounds like Step 5 is the problem: "Update the appsettings.json configuration for the bot to use the Microsoft App Id and App Password from the Bot Framework registration."

Comment: As stated thats already been done and checked three times.  The client id and the secret are the same. I even tried deleting the secret and creating a new one.

Comment: Where you have stored Microsoft App Id and Microsoft User name ? As of now I am not able to see such kind of keys in client secrets..

Comment: This was a project for a client, i ended up getting it to work by creating everything using the CLI as opposed though though the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread but I just got hit by this today. After much pain, the fix in our situation was this:

1. Go to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory
2. Click "App registrations"
3. Find the registration for the bot app in question and click on it.
4. Under Manage, choose Authentication.
5. **Change "Supported account types" to "Accounts in any organizational directory."**

In retrospect: the AADSTS700016 error was thrown when trying to get the detailed info of the person the bot is chatting with via `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync()`. Since our "Supported account types" in the app registration was restricted, when the bot was running in a Teams Office365 Tenant that was different than our Azure AD Tenant, Azure AD was saying, "Nope." After flipping this, then `GetMemberAsync()` was able to authenticate aginst the Teams Office365 Tenant to obtain the requested user information. Yay!